# Cassandra UDT with Version 2

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I want to use cassandra c++ driver. Its still working on version 2. (binary protocol version 2)
I want to use this to connect to cassandra 2.1
Is it possible to create a prepared statement and insert a UDT value into it.

or UDT can only be used with protocol version 3

regards

Answer (score 2):

UDT are only available in cassandra 2.1 (and later)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5590

Comment: Hello, I understand that they are available only in cassandra 2.1. We intend to use C++ driver, which supports only binary protocol 2, I want to test if we can use it to connect to cassandra 2.1 and use udt feature

Comment: How do you plan to test if the driver doesn't support them? https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-96